# Handy way to connect PostgreSQL from an out-of-box application? (Embedding PostgreSQL)

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL in my application to manage some records.
With SQLite, nothing complicated was needed because it's a file db.

However, with PostgreSQL, some settings should be done before use it even if I want to connect localhost or local socket file.
Of course, initialization is only required once but the problem is, I don't want to bother any use of my application with this system setting problem.
I want to make it possible for users to just run and use my application out-of-box state.

I've read a wiki article to use PostgreSQL in Arch Linux(https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL), and no one would like to do these things to use my application.
Furthermore, it's not possible to run those commands in wiki from application because the specific settings are depends on distros and also requires root-privileges.

Is there any way to connect PostgreSQL without such complicated initialization, like SQLite? Or, simple way to make the user's system prepared?

Just for your information, my application is written in C++ and Qt.
And, I cannot use SQLite for its limitations.

Comment: I'm not a database wizard, but I think PostgreSQL is mostly used for server side data bases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an embedded database PostgreSQL isn't a great choice. It's usable, but it's a bit clunky compared to DBs designed for embedding like [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/), SQLite, etc.

### Bundling PostgreSQL

If you want to use PostgreSQL, I suggest bundling PostgreSQL binaries with your program, and starting a PostgreSQL server up when your program is used - assuming you only need a single instance of your program at a time. You can get handy pre-built Pg binaries [from EDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload). You can offer your users a choice on startup - "Use existing PostgreSQL" (in which case they must create the user and db themselves, make any pg_hba.conf changes, etc) or "Start private PostgreSQL server" (when you run your own using the binaries you bundled).

If they want to use an existing DB, all you need to do is tell them to enter the host / socket_directory, database name, port, username, and password. Don't make "password" required, it might be blank if their hba configuration doesn't require one.

If they want to use a private instance, you fire one up - see the guidance below.

**Please *do not* bundle a PostgreSQL *installer* and run it as a silent install**. This is a nightmare for the poor user, who has no idea where this "postgresql" thingy came from and is likely to uninstall it. Or, worse, it'll conflict with their own PostgreSQL install, or confuse them when they go to install PostgreSQL themselves later, finding that they already have it and *don't even know the password*. Yeah. Don't do that. Bundle the binaries only and control your private PostgreSQL install yourself.

**Do not just use the `postgres` executables already on the system to make your own private instance**. If the user decides to upgrade from 9.2 to 9.3, suddenly your private instance won't start up, and you won't have access to the old 9.2 binaries to do a `pg_upgrade`. You need to take full responsibility if you're using a private instance of Pg and bundle the binaries you need in your program.

### How to start/control a private instance of Pg

On first run, you run PostgreSQL's `initdb -D /path/to/datadir`, pointing at an empty subdir of a private data directory for your program. Set some environment variables first so you don't conflict with any normal PostgreSQL install on the system. In particular, set `PGPORT` to some random high-ish port, and specify a different `unix_socket_directory` configuration parameter to the default.

Once `initdb` has run, your program will probably want to modify `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` to fit its needs. Personally I don't bother, I just pass any parameters I want as overrides on the PostgreSQL server start-up command line, including overriding the `hba_file` to point to one I have pre-created.

If the data dir already exists during program startup you then need to check whether the datadir matches the current PostgreSQL major version by examining the `PG_VERSION` file. If it doesn't, you need to make a copy of the datadir and run `pg_upgrade` to upgrade it to the current version you have bundled. You need to retain a copy of the binaries for the old version for this, so you'll need to special-case your update processes or just bundle old versions of the binaries in your update installer as well as the new ones.

When your program is started, after it's checked that the datadir already exists and is the correct version, set the `PGPORT` env var to the same value you used for `initdb` then start PostgreSQL directly with `postgres -D /path/to/datadir` and suitable parameters for log file output, etc. The postmaster you start will have your program as the parent executable, and will be terminated if your program quits suddenly. That's OK, it'll get time to clean up, and even if it doesn't PostgreSQL is crash-safe by design. Your program should still [politely ask PostgreSQL to shut down before exiting by sending an appropriate signal](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-shutdown.html), though.

Your application can now connect to the PostgreSQL instance it owns and controls using libpq or whatever, as normal, by specifying the port you're running it on and (if making a unix socket connection) passing `host` as `/path/to/whatever/unix/socket/dir`.

Instead of directly controlling `postgres` you might instead choose to use `pg_ctl` to drive it. That way you can leave the database running when your program exits and only start it if you find it's not already running. It doesn't really matter if the user shuts the system down without shutting down PostgreSQL - Pg will generally get some shutdown warning from the operating system, but doesn't need it or care much about it, it's quite happy to just crash and recover when next started up.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitily not as easy as using SQLite.
In SQLite you have only a single file which contains the whole database and if you "connect" to the database you simply open the file.
In PostgreSQL, MySQL, ... you have a database daemon which keeps lots of files open, you have multiple files for the database itself, then transaction logs, log files .. and of course the configuration files which specifify where all these files are, resource usage, how to connect and much more. And the database  needs also be maintained regularly for optimal performance and there are lots of tunables. That's all because the usual use of all these databases is to serve multiple clients at once as fast as possible and not to make setup simple.

It is still possible to setup PostgreSQL just for a single user. To setup the database you need to create a database directory, find an unused port on localhost for TCP connections or better use UNIX domain sockets, write the config with the needed parameters (like the used socket, database directory, user, resource restrictions, permissions so that no other users on the same machine can connect), start the database daemon, initialize the database(s) (postgresql can serve multiple databases within the same daemon setup) and finally connect to the database from your program. And don't forget to regularly run the maintainance tasks and to shutdown the database in an ordered way.